# Which version of HTML by QtWebView?

Tags: python, html, pyside, qtwebkit

I am trying to make an app by `QtWebKit`.

But `QtWebView` can't play Movies on (f.e) YouTube.

I heard that `html5` has video tag.

Is `QtWebView` adoptable for `html5`?

I know `QtWebEngine` is already adoptable for html5.

Is `html5` available from `PyQt5` or `PySide2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found out it just a moment.

from [Here](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebSettings.html?highlight=html5)

> WebKit provides support for features specified in HTML 5 that improve the performance and capabilities of Web applications. These include client-side (offline) storage and the use of a Web application cache.

WebKit provides support for features specified in HTML5

So I understood WebView uses HTML5.

Thanks.